# FFI and static libraries used in application

Tags: haskell, crash, static-libraries, ffi

I wrote a Haskell library that links against a C library – a *static* one. Compilation is done perfectly, and `cabal repl` gives me access to the functions imported from the static C lib.

Now, if I install my library in a sandbox of an application I’m writing, and run the application, it crashes at startup. `cabal repl` and using the C functions in the app sandbox works perfectly.

Moreover, I’m on Windows 64-bit and the exit code of the application is 9, which is ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK. [More info here](http://lpaste.net/8641330300967714816).

I don’t have any clue why the application doesn’t run… Any idea folks?

Comment: "It crashes" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: I know right :( It silently exits

Comment: What's the exit code? Have you run with GDB?

Comment: I’m on Windows. The exit code is 9

Comment: If you could provide us with actual code, I could try compiling it on my machine.

Comment: Sure. `cabal update`, `cabal install al`, and [this code](http://lpaste.net/121536). `al` exports symbols with standard `foreign import`.